# Maximum likelihood programming in Stata

Tags: optimization, stata

I am trying to learn `ml` programming in Stata. As a part of this I am running a program `myprobit` (the code is adopted from Maximum likelihood estimation with Stata by Gould, Pitblado, and Sribney).

```
capture program drop myprobit
program define myprobit
args todo b lnf g negH g1
tempvar xb lj
mleval `xb'=`b'
quietly{
gen double `lj'=normal(`xb') if $ML_y1==1
replace `lj'=normal(-`xb') if $ML_y1==0
mlsum `lnf'=ln(`lj')
if (`todo'==0|`lnf'>= .) exit
replace `g1'= normalden(`xb')/`lj' if $ML_y1==1
replace `g1'=-normalden(`xb')/`lj' if $ML_y1==0
mlvecsum `lnf' `g'=`g1', eq(1)
if (`todo'==1|`lnf'==>.)exit
mlmatsum `lnf' `negH'=`g1'*(`g1'+`xb'),eq(1,1)
}
end

sysuse cancer, clear
gen drug2=drug==2
gen drug3=drug==3
ml model d1 myprobit (died=drug2 drug3 age)
ml check
ml maximize
```

But, I got an error `varlist required`:
Here is a trace of its execution:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-> myprobit 1 __000000 __000001 __000002 __000003 
          - `begin'
          = capture noisily version 11: myprobit 1 __000000 __000001 __000002 __000003 
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- begin myprobit ---
            - args todo b lnf g negH g1
            - tempvar xb lj
            - mleval `xb'=`b'
            = mleval __000005=__000000
            - quietly{
            - gen double `lj'=normal(`xb') if $ML_y1==1
            = gen double __000006=normal(__000005) if died==1
            - replace `lj'=normal(-`xb') if $ML_y1==0
            = replace __000006=normal(-__000005) if died==0
            - mlsum `lnf'=ln(`lj')
            = mlsum __000001=ln(__000006)
            - if (`todo'==0|`lnf'>= .) exit
            = if (1==0|__000001>= .) exit
            - replace `g1'= normalden(`xb')/`lj' if $ML_y1==1
            = replace = normalden(__000005)/__000006 if died==1
varlist required
              replace `g1'=-normalden(`xb')/`lj' if $ML_y1==0
              mlvecsum `lnf' `g'=`g1', eq(1)
              if (`todo'==1|`lnf'==>.)exit
              mlmatsum `lnf' `negH'=`g1'*(`g1'+`xb'),eq(1,1)
              }
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ end myprobit ---
          - `end'
          = set trace off
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fix myprobit.
r(100);

end of do-file
```

Note: The program runs without an error if likelihood evaluator is changed to `do`. 
Any suggestion in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You provided 5 arguments to your program, but 6 are needed. Hence local macro `g1` is not defined, which bites when you try to `replace` the variable it names.

Stata is telling you some of this. The lines

```
- replace `g1'= normalden(`xb')/`lj' if $ML_y1==1
= replace = normalden(__000005)/__000006 if died==1
```

show that local macro `g1` is interpreted as nothing, i.e. an empty string, so Stata complains because it expects a variable name after `replace`.

The line

```
if (`todo'==1|`lnf'==>.)exit
```

is also problematic, as the operator `==>` should be `>=`.

These are the problems I noticed; there may be others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As to the `g1`, the book says that it is a `double`variable generated by `ml` program, so we are just replacing the numerical gradient computed by `ml` program with the analytical gradient provided in the code. Yes, the operator  ==> should be replaced by >=.